# material community icons do not show in react native

Tags: react-native

Hello in my account screen my icons are not showing up, Here is the react naitve code, which include how i am implementing the icons, please help me regarding this issue, I am trying to build on account screen which include the icons and other information :

```
import React from 'react'  
import { View , StyleSheet, SafeAreaView ,FlatList} from 'react-native'  
import Icon from '../components/Icon'  
import ListItem from '../components/lists/ListItem'  
import colors from '../config/colors'  
import Screen from "../components/Screen"  
import ListItemSeperator from '../components/lists/ListItemSeperator'  

const menuItems = [  
    {  
        title: "My Listings",   
        icon: {  
            name: "format-list-bulleted",  
            backgroundColor: colors.primary,  
    }  
},    
{  
        title: "My Messages",  
        icon: {  
            name: "email",  
            backgroundColor: colors.secondary,  
        }  
      }   
]   

function AccountScreen(props) {  
    return (  
     <Screen style={styles.body}>  
         <View style={styles.container}>  
         <ListItem   
         title="Veraat Gupta"  
         subTitle="guptasgurgaon@gmail.com"  
         image={require("../assets/mosh.jpg")}  
         />  
         </View>  
         <View style={styles.container}>  
            <FlatList   
            data={menuItems}  
            keyExtractor={menuItem => menuItem.title}  
            ItemSeparatorComponent={ListItemSeperator}  
            renderItem= {({ item }) =>   
                <ListItem   
                title={item.title}  
                ImageComponent={  
                    <Icon   
                    name= {item.icon.name}  
                    backgroundColor= {item.icon.backgroundColor}  
                    size= {46}/>  
                }  
                  
                />  
            }  
            />
         </View>
         <View style={styles.container}>
         <ListItem 
                title= "Logout"
                ImageComponent={
                    <Icon
                    name= "logout"
                    backgroundColor= {colors.log_out}
                    size={46}/>
                }
                />
         </View>
     </Screen>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({  
    container: {  
        marginHorizontal: 0 ,  
        padding:0,  
        marginVertical: 20,  
        width: "100%",  
    },  
    body: {  
        backgroundColor: colors.light,  
    },  
    user:{  
        width: "100%",  
    },  
    listing: {  
        backgroundColor: colors.white,  
        
    }  
})  
export default AccountScreen
```

here is a photo
https://photos.app.goo.gl/xNnnrRFybsaSGV2e6
copy and paste it

Comment: Can you please paste the Icon component code ?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1be4leFyGkwyJuxgrMCto2qnBqGvu-i_GmqyXMmIlMz0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: first of all install react-native-vector-icons using npm or yarn

Answer (score 0):

run: `npm install --save react-native-vector-icons`

more info: https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons

```
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements';
        
<Icon type="material-community" name="logout" />
```

Comment: code for icon component

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1be4leFyGkwyJuxgrMCto2qnBqGvu-i_GmqyXMmIlMz0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: icon is a custom component https://docs.google.com/document/d/1be4leFyGkwyJuxgrMCto2qnBqGvu-i_GmqyXMmIlMz0/edit

code